# C# Regex find multiple HTML tags in one pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have a random message (I don't know what will be the content) however, I know that is may contain HTML tags like `<b>` and `<a href=>`  ... then I know that there is no more HTML tag than these.
So, I am looking for a pattern which will be able to recognize and get the content between bold markup, also  hyperlink and its content.
I already did this code:

```
string pattern = "(<b>(.*)</b>)|(<a href=.*?>(.*?)<\\/a>)";
Match match = Regex.Match(content, pattern);
while (match.Success)

      if (match.Groups[0].Value.Contains("<b>"))
      {
            messageBlock.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
            {
                   messageBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run(content.Substring(0, match.Index)));
                   messageBlock.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run(match.Groups[1].Value)));
             });
       }
       else if (match.Groups[0].Value.Contains("<a href="))
       }
}
```

Nevertheless with this pattern, I can't recover the content match by example `<a href=?>` ... It only works for the bold tag..
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `@"(?s)<(?:(a)(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>""']|""[^""]*""|'[^']*')*?\shref\s*=(?:(['""])(.*?)\2))\s+(?:"".*?""|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+|b\s*)>(.*?)</(?(1)a|b)\s*>"`

Where

- If Grp1 matched the `a` was found , otherwise the `b` was found
- Grp 2 disregard
- Grp 3 contains href value if grp1 matched
- Grp 4 contains contents

[PCRE demo](https://regex101.com/r/pekJeU/1)
but works for C#

Comment: Thank you ! However It only gives  the content of the <a> tag and not its href value... I need both :$

Comment: Modified it to get link

Answer (score 2):

For parsing html is better to use [Html Agility pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/)

Comment: This is  comment , not answer

Comment: I can't really use it in my case

Comment: why you cannot use it?